# Investigating Memory Leak

Tags: windows, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks, windbg

We have a slow memory leak in our application and I've already gone through the following steps in trying to analyize the cause for the leak:

1. Enabling user mode stack trace database in GFlags
2. In Windbg, typing the following command: **!heap -stat -h 1250000** (where 1250000 is the address of the heap that has the leak)
   After comparing multiple dumps, I see that a memory blocks of size **0xC** are increasing over time and are probably the memory that is leaked.
3. typing the following command: **!heap -flt s c**
   gives the UserPtr of those allocations and finally:
4. typing **!heap -p -a address** on some of those addresses always shows the following allocation call stack:

0:000> **!heap -p -a 10576ef8**

```
address 10576ef8 found in
_HEAP @ 1250000
  HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
    10576ed0 000a 0000  [03]   10576ef8    0000c - (busy)
    mscoreei!CLRRuntimeInfoImpl::`vftable'
    7c94b244 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+0x00000044
    7c919c0c ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x00000e64
    603b14a4 mscoreei!UtilExecutionEngine::ClrHeapAlloc+0x00000014
    603b14cb mscoreei!ClrHeapAlloc+0x00000023
    603b14f7 mscoreei!ClrAllocInProcessHeapBootstrap+0x0000002e
    603b1614 mscoreei!operator new[]+0x0000002b
    603d402b +0x0000005f
    603d5142 mscoreei!GetThunkUseState+0x00000025
    603d6fe8 mscoreei!_CorDllMain+0x00000056
    79015012 mscoree!ShellShim__CorDllMain+0x000000ad
    7c90118a ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x00000014
    7c919a6d ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x000000c0
    7c9198e6 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x00000219
    7c90e457 ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher+0x00000007
```

This looks like thread initialization call stack but I need to know more than this.
What is the next step you would recommend to do in order to put the finger at the exact cause for the leak.

Answer (score 6):

The stack recorded when using GFlags is done without utilizing .pdb and often not correct.
Since you have traced the leak down to a specific size on a given heap, you can try
to set a live break in RtlAllocateHeap and inspect the stack in windbg with proper symbols. I have used the following with some success. You must edit it to suit your heap and size.

```
 $$ Display stack if heap handle eq 0x00310000 and size is  0x1303
 $$ ====================================================================
bp ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap "j ((poi(@esp+4) = 0x00310000) & (poi(@esp+c) = 0x1303) )'k';'gc'"
```

Maybe you then get another stack and other ideas for the offender.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that the new operator is the `new []` operator so is there a corresponding `delete[]` call and not a plain old `delete` call?

If you suspect this code I would put a test harness around it, for instance put it in a loop and execute it 100 or 1000 times, does it still leak and proportionally.

You can also measure the memory increase using process explorer or programmatically using [GetProcessInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The other obvious thing is to see what happens when you comment out this function call, does the memory leak go away? You may need to do a binary chop if possible of the code to reduce the likely suspect code by half (roughly) each time by commenting out code, however, changing the behaviour of the code may cause more problems or dependant code path issues which can cause memory leaks or strange behaviour.

**EDIT**
Ignore the following seeing as you are working in a managed environment.

You may also consider using the `STL` or better yet [boost](http://www.boost.org) reference counted pointers like [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or [scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) for array structures to manage the lifetime of the objects.

Comment: While the language isn't specified the presence of mscoreei!* suggests this is a managed language so the need for delete, the use of STL, boost, etc probably don't apply.

Comment: The problem is that this callstack shows CLR code and not my code so I don't know where to search.

Comment: It looks like it is loading some dll as I see a dllmain like call, what is mscoreei? I don't know anything about .net is this your dll or a 3rd party, not a MS .net dll? it is highly unlikely that a MS dll is leaking memory so it could be something to do with incorrect usage by the calling code you could set a breakpoint on the function `bp mscoreei!GetThunkUseState` and when this is called check the call stack and see if that gives you more info than the post mortem dump

Comment: mscoreei is part of the .net framework. Therefore, the whole callstack that I posted is not part the client code so I can't put break point.

Comment: You can still put a breakpoint in mscoreei, if it gets hits too many times then you can set the breakpoint only when it hits your code.