# Analysis of extreme private bytes usage in .Net application, native memory leak?

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, windbg, unmanaged-memory

We have a .Net website running, which is using an extreme amount of private bytes: 4,45 GBytes and up.
This has occurred on multiple webservers, but there does not seem to be a pattern.

With the help of some other answers and of course [the blog of Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/), we got a lot of information already, using [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798) and WinDbg (part of [Win8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852363)):

- We know there's only a single allocation that is consuming over 3 GBytes:
  [image]
- We know it's native memory:
  [image]
- We know it's allocated on Heap 1:
  [image]

From here on we are stuck.
The suggested commands (!heap -stat -h, !heap -flt s and !heap -p -a), that can also be found [here](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html), do not provide us with information on the cause of this behavior.

Has anyone seen this before?  Are there other ways or commands to see what is causing nativerd (Native Code Configuration Reader of IIS) to go berserk?

Answer (score 0):

Load sos dll in windbg .

Try !dumpheap -stat in windbg. This will return all the objects in the heap.

Traverse the heap and see which object is created more in number and analyze if that object still need to be in memory or should be garbage collected long back.

Collect such objects and do !gcroot , you will be able to see which parent object is holding your objetcts from getting garbage collected. This will help you narrow down your memory leak.

Most common memory leaks occur due to usage of events in .net. A class A would have subscribed to class B's event. Unless or otherwise Class B is garbage collected object A would still reside in memory.

**Update:**

For native memory leaks, use [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  in the codebase. The blocks which leak memory will be displayed in the output window if you are using visual studio

[Glowcode](http://www.glowcode.com/) also allows you to detect native memory leaks.

Comment: thanks for answering. But we're not talking about a managed memory leak, which is most common. And the number of objects is not increasing, we only have one single object, but cannot get to it in Windbg.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But this is a C++ function? Our application is written in C#. And it seems to have the same purpose as the LeakTrack.dll used by DebugDiag. We didn't know Glowcode yet, might have a go on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Since its one huge allocation, you could use Windbg to set a break and inspect the call stack. See my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030349/investigating-memory-leak/10086789#10086789)  for how to set such a break. NB this is for 32 bits, you must probably adjust it for 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a DebugDiag noob, but I think the next step should be looking at the call stack samples provided in the module report by DebugDiag to see what causes these allocations. From your screenshot, it looks like you have already clicked on the offending function. What is shown at that section of the DebugDiag report?
Also, how do you know it's a single allocation?