# Heap Corruption double freeing memory

Tags: c++, windbg, heap-corruption

I have a Heap corruption crash for an application and so I turned on page heap from gflags and collected a crash dump file for that application.

From the dump file I found out that it is due to double freeing the memory.

Here is an example, From the call stack I found this

```
msvcr100!free(void * pBlock = "**Address**")
```

Then I did this

```
!heap -p -a <address>

address found in
_HEAP @ 
  HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
    Address 000a 0000  [02]   address    00003 - **(free )**
Trace: <1>
       <2>
       <3>
```

So we can see that it is trying to double free the memory and that resulted in crash. My question is can we see the call stack that changed or freed that memory before this operation? Is it possible?

I can see a trace below the !heap -p -a command is that the one that freed the memory? If it is so, I can see only some part of call stack, Is there any way I can see the total call stack or walk through the call stack manually to see which operation freed that block of memory.

Comment: You are asking for a time machine, a dump file doesn't have one.

Comment: Yes, I have some knowledge that a dump file is snapshot at that point of time but just curious if enabling full page heap can give little more information than who is trying to free the memory like who already freed the memory?

Comment: You should probably enable page heap to get yourself started - page heap use bit patterns to mark memory so corruptions (as double use) are easier to catch. Also, this link should be helpful: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHeapCorruption-7a727b6a

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code you can replace the delete/free functions with your own functions that can capture the stack just before the release actually happens.

On windows you can get the call stack using the function `CaptureStackBackTrace` however this functions returns a set of pointers and you need to translate them to symbol names.
To do that you can use `SymInitialize`, then for each pointer you can use `SymFromAddr` to get the name of the symbol. The names are the actual functions that you are searching for.

However it would be easier to use a debugger on windows. There is also `Application Verifier` which is an application from microsoft that can help you capture heap corruptions (when used with the visual studio debugger).

Hope this helps
Razvan.

Comment: Thanks Raxvan, so there is no possibility to check the function which freed the memory first before the one in call stack tried to free the memory in Windbg?

Comment: Yes there is , you need to keep track of freed pointer. You can keep a sed of pointers that you have freed and when you free the pointer again check against the set if the pointer is still present. Inside the set you can also keep the callstack

Answer (score 0):

If you run the debug version, there is a fair chance that you will see more of the call stack.

See also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030349/investigating-memory-leak/10086789#10086789)